# Hit counter in php

Tags: php, web, hitcounter

I'm using simple php script to count visits. It's saved inside file. So there is a number inside a .txt file and I would like to put on my page in a form of some nice counter. So I need numbers to be represented as images in some way. So it can look nice. If I eventually had div where I can show this numbers, and 10 images of numbers from 0 to 9. 25x50px lets say and I would like to put them into  tags is that possible?
I know my question is a bit dodgy and maybe not clear. But if someone understand what I'm asking for than if you could answer that would be great. Thx

Answer (score 2):

Split the number into digits:

```
$a = str_split(1337, 1);
```

Use the array to create the counter:

```
foreach ($a as $n) {
    print '<img src="'.$n.'.png">';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the number from the file:

```
$number = file_get_contents('visitors.txt');
```

To create an image, use the [GD](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) or [Imagick](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) library:

```
header("Content-type: image/png");
$im = imagecreatefrompng("images/button1.png");
// Add text to $im
imagepng($im);
```

To include your image in a page:

```
<img src="myImageScript.php?number=1234" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. First you need to get the number in char array and the proceed. Based on number display the images nest to each other.

Comment: That is exactly what I was thinking. But I don't know how to separate numbers and put them to position they should be. lets say in file there is 172 so how to separate it and put it to position 000000172?

Comment: You can prepend zeroes ny using [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php). For example `sprintf('%09d', 172)` will give 000000172.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is only showing the number as images, it's easy. Do something like:

```
$num = 1234;
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($num); $i++)
  echo "<img src=\"images/numbers/" . $num.{$i} . ".png\">";
```

Answer (score 0):

have 10 images for the numbers 0-9 (0.png, 1.png, ...) and just convert every character in a string `$counter="12345"` into a corresponding image `<img src="1.png" />`

this is explained and implemented in javascript on this [website](http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/169321-how-display-numbers-images-nuff-easy).

you may also want to [`str_pad`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) your $counter with `0`.